# Флаг O_RfR в open()

Tags: c

Что значит флаг O_RfR в функции open()?

Например

```
int q = open (argv[1], O_RfR);
```

В оригинале в аргументе командной строки передается имя бинарного файла.
Потом к этому `q` обращаются через lseek

Comment: O_RDONLY, O_WRONLY, O_RDWR, O_APPEND, O_BINARY, O_TEXT

O_RfR  - нету такого (хотя я могу ошибаться)

Comment: В оригинале в аргументе командной строки передается имя бинарного файла.
Потом к этому `q` обращаются через lseek

Comment: перед этой строкой (открытия файла) напишите что то вида

    printf("O_RfR = %d\n, O_RfR);

и покажите вывод. Это с 99% вероятностью define, определенный у Вас в коде и с 1% вероятностью - от какого хитрого компилятора или специфических хедеров оси.